# Json information downloaded from an url is encrypted

Tags: php, json, curl

I have been trying to download some information about the aircraft routes from a transponder for a while ...

By accessing a url with CURL the result is encrypted or encrypted nush why?

code:

```
function curl_download($url) {

            //  Initiate curl
        $ch = curl_init();
        // Will return the response, if false it print the response
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        // Set the url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        // Execute
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
        // Closing
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
 }


$data = curl_download("http://can.vicosh.ro:8000/VirtualRadar/AircraftList.json");

echo $data;
$myJSON = json_decode($data, true);

echo "<pre>";
  print_r($myJSON);
echo "</pre>"
```

> ���`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{���{���;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"~�GM=������<�5=��/�����l���W�4/.�����'w�����h�Ѫ*��eY�=j�u�KF��^��������c����ï|{�ޫ�~c߾�E^_���e5�ʰ�yV6�����W�x��@�gD6WW��Rz�?����/���K�./�M��߾�ѣ�6�>/����0��>�'ȯ��5S��Y�
>   ������4���㝃�B�I6��ʩ�G�ϫ�'���z�:ϗ���{�i��[���޻�����|z���{�Z�y�O�v�N�h.��qپ��a��h&����tL�����������߶��\�@�'�=
>   �*̈D��/>O|��w�Y��Ty���?O^������=�����&�����}�����/�N?�*~�)?�)�~��
>   ���*�y�}��(�������/A���E�^����EE��Z��j�-��#�ϖm^�M�;�?+��yۜ��{��/��D4�;:�����q��[���ɳH����l��po�ާ�7�ƹa�ㆽ����/�O~r7�?x��0������0;F��|��?>�z|���wv���c�=�A<����������f�ѽ��O?��x�eռ)
>   ���;���%�4�0�=�Ɵv����7ĳ�@_���˝�f����y��y�H��jV�4��t�x�y�;y�_Y[T��ɺ�5)}ڤǟ����;Pq»���B,���+�$3�����;�����eA��^$n3�����{����=�޽oy���{�wn���,K�;�9>��,�t����� K����4d�����{���}���c��ާ���&�ܹ�p���{=�֗0t�����>?��0���Ӈ�I���~���n�����ݿ���?�3L~�޽�A\��ۃ��>.�ɚ�>K�vw_?�.�8����^{���矿z�>-���ΚQ����Mz֔�r6J?���
>   ����������k���U�9}�פ8����TK�<}V�/fE�$[� ��
>   Ń��Q��Y������{��0�ǅ�����a�b����c�c}ixs�����i�t�޽�48{O0
>   ��ppp����׿�뽧_y�����������݃�н}����y#�����{x_4~����=����{��qo��������+�n�HO�E����ͺ~��QϿN_�붽�������w+⟆?љ#
>   YV'y��Y�Q�Q^�#x_V���~����2{�����?�ٗ�)����{�&������<�2`���?}���ޞe��=a`"��������̽���Ͼ�c��?�ʲ����C��������ݽ��o�+������mv��|�v��p^ �H��Y���Cȋ��g����뺢f��n�'���/��Z7���:/&��b��Ίe���Zd
>   ���ҙ���x�f�u���J�'E���OBu�x<ؽ�l��߰t >�)ˠ���0}�ݽ���ţg
>   a����2���O�>��~꜕�=r"obP(5��|zr�����_~��f�ݝ{�;�ʧ���Z���������<�{+������`f���=�4�z���ν����\���tOXS$�G�]�)k�W���Kg}Rm��SjsE�ϪO���(�>���l��QN��P
>   ��a�=�aw=�\��7$��X����ÇQ�%��;��A��{����OC���l4��}�s��܇�|���r��ͷ���w�W�
>   �_fs(^���)�~%Y��_)��������!~�}��>Lw78P�9��͓�������ߎ(�l��d]v���Ͼx��(����?���y:����z�y��d�M��yՓ������;�˽{�{?;b�]�O?�f��]��7�Z�C�{@_��}����O3}��=�҇�h�{^�����0?9�?��2?�f��^h����|�Xhy]}WR��Z!]���t�M������{�{��MP�y��?��Q�$��/�e6��ѿo��^�ʅ&�>�2�����}����^x����ٔ��;7��~6��ާ�ST�?�l���Q�.��{�;��)�ac��;N����7f�Ջv���Sx�&��w@�z?��m�Y��t��r�sV<T�{�C�PR������pZ�2�>���|��KJ�ϲ�L��Xg9Mi���j��zI9+����>�{AV�io�k+�ݽ�T��}��)��>mL-�����-E��W��}�2.�~w��pR��pp�O}Y�t�V��w_�P`���/��s����c��i)3���#{y��?p��ÞO�S�$�@Z��S��}�����yV/�Ӓ~ɋ��~@������
>   �q���~�'O�'U}ݬ
>   �߫�/G�WokʻX���rF�S9��g}"�e��������v��a��̿��-���{�d#<����������I<���'O�����a.�̙�����X�V�Ƈ;p
>   Ъ;�4����{�v�9���n��i�����${��$���먱����
>   9�}�,�]c^�|%�}�L�t����ѿ8=��e^��(}I�H���Ȑ�<�/bF��,��~<��>�p������e������e؋[''���A��E���j��O
>   G��%�t��
>   ��9�����'��-DC_Q��}�D��DqƮ���=�D�]�O��Dc����vu-�'{;ヽN��p�������qR�����~��+o�wmM�g��:A������{{����:}Y,�������e��ӽ7�9��wc��:�'_���EZ�ks��J�{x��,ޔ6wN���O�yů��O���N��y��>����kIVջ�����J��~!��s�>��;�<��������}��}��t�e=o��G�a���������hM��!�\f�E�u���!�t��~;[�BR'�=����N���Y�S0�:QȲ������?;�U�����{�����������F�~׹5��w}��?n��}Z���:Fax���"���?ܹ?����=/O)���9�M���Oԭ���������������ܠ�<����ݻ��g�mY�{��*�c��,���������=��|=V
>   <��'$�7�ꁋ>�zE��ϩ���
>   �G��~g�hΩ�2�!�h�*�Si���S1����./������T�S�ia)��I���L�P]���3vwi�s��������v�����]��γv^WWnvrX�{=����k}�����)96��#��q���h�����Ԟp�����b����3�>�q�wY�Gtzþ�eA�ϋN���8��Wo����Ã�O�u���F8v������j|h%�B��������v����֐'5�o�ּ��٧��#�?~Hz�[���
>   �J?�.V=x��ԍ>����{�O�����JZ8��=L��ݽ������y��I���x�`�S�&�r��H�駻X����7���}]'�L
>   �w����^~c�<Ōw���d���f��Ms�uy��_�=�!3_�=﹠����W��=�ƚ�����@�o���>���烃��|��a�{���΁Ϟ�d�����=����S�io�(<��;�F��[Կ��"I$�>��hl����a�֘�y����O>'a�~���m&�
>   /�ɾ�+\g�[���h�������ϥŜ:��)KO~�O��|����R���T�\������}�����r������3�dxQ��k��ǯ��;.=}���p�f7c�r���������+���{����AC���[e��m/�`�n�rɻ���_Q��{?������ON��و��ν���ܧ{;7�O%�:]ӊN�@!�Yqؿ�:�7-gu�cy_y�������7h�O������v���Z(��{p
>   ���|�����K>#��yd��r�K>��:����w#��8�ߔ��u��?RY���.�y,����@��Q��a��B�"[�?�ϻ���P�c,/��F9�"�=�*O�����]Z�C>y���c����R�Y���ӟ:~6��~J�C�s�8�81���[c�t��rbN��![�҆��]Z������;>��ZDy��΃�y?Xq'�r|?��wX,�$��@-ے����Ct\�Zġ��E�j����\��յ��q����ûpY]��`?�P�y�S��arv�t���s����C��S�v߼.���7�!�-2��g�ۿ��?�iyx��޿�;�g}���.Ӳ�j��M�j�9�e~�5`�H�HCt,����W�#�>��~̺����۽wCz�cՓ��'p�����
>   ��Gɉ��Ua3�gq�;�ν��:W��������[��;_|�-9�����M����`�]u0��w��4�m(��A~6�mo�t������bY��M��C�����ǹ�H���_�m�x��D�;\�$~�D�Z��b���Z:+�=}�r�a�l
>   �a<�O�jMw-�{���u7�Ȋ��1t7�[��ZM�ۍG�;��������Q�Q��\
>   a|����������x罗+�K6/U~��
>   k�ߴ5��K��X�y��J�JI����Z��WgxP����{���=r�<�ۧ����&�a����K^�����6�^\��a����z��sݬ
>   Z���������R�oi���?#|�SN�����{���7$$���{��)#�}q�>�����b���.xR)v|���};�����a�@K/�X�ݝ]u��[yRB���|oۿ1{`��\P���������Uo�Z�v�Hh�0|���X����
>   ����i�<[��y]5���`T(�dX�yA�m֤�`�U]4yC�u���J����6�ݐ�{�Ҕ�[{_�����1�|��MJ���������p�\��N��!���]��"��|�OVSnn�^̛o�>{��­�����Zᥚ��A8n��%E¼����������>=�#o�}'}�M�y�~���o�ѿ2_"8l��d]zθ81g�����j�ճ*}��?Y,�E���X/�)�W�o��>�NC@�fM$��|���7��IDT}�O��°�k�`��޽{�����X�<���k�o�u��������{�*$-��S���?��O+m{����÷Q�|��T�1�����9ˬzI��&��X�[6��nS}�!�7��!�E��>O���ˋ:��^o)���FSR���ۑ�v_�F�c���n4����w#{~��D�M*<֏9����
>   ���9���X>�k��|9Ƞ�З!�B
>   �U��T�U�߽U�I���O"Mk\��{�d���O�����hnt-x.���p���j���{�w
>   �Rz;|�?����P�UKb笝�����5<ͫ<9N�����_�6���K=�ۿɻ6��My�_[=�1���y�9ה�{p��_����O�>�lE���8�O鎽pM�<�=����C7��}�x;��{���o�齝�����w��#����8+{�������3.�~gc���lcT����.��rI��xM����7�_����V�4{U,{?�ݿa������"{?��|=�&��y4nʯ<�w�}���8������'O����}�`���~���r�~�]��������ރ}?y�t��G��)3�{�r������G���`���U���C��X�yx{�����{{H�Y���kr�ˌL��>�����8��!-j��^O��j^�b���Fn]�t�ꜭ��u;�+y"�����b���E)q~_Q
>   u�uE��j���}�,\���Ӹ�C���?!�r��:���y������%Q^���OYeI����˭?��a\�?�G&�FQ��7���3��$�۟nZ�D������_����{}����CI��O��_?�G�|���u׭��J�*8��~�ؕ����x������/��+-\�w�]p�͢<��s/��`�������sʼ������&�r/-�P������I�?�t��(�~�$��KC�"��;�T(��A*�/���
>   8e
>   �Bn�GV��~����i��ͫK$TB'y���/�ߋ�C[ʦ��^�Y��/�紎�B��?�Awq��d%���CVa�~������"���߲��y���+�
>   *%P�o�J�{~˓�;��ٟ��'�i�{�%ܻ�a�O]X� �~�7���`��V�XV����o�{n�����v2�}'��{7�Ľ=';dDN�2�����?��H&v�te˛*�;�T���o�њ�
>   ��͗_|��
>   \w)P��6䶑P��ֽ�[H������O��+���HR$������u�{s��s�������ˬ���|��W/ғl9�G���/�wŴ2���3��Uvfl�������m�
>   �}�a9����C������t��Fq��<$J\��n����� ���tMă��C��q����
>   u��\f�����݇N�%z���΀K���-����Ҵ�;�������=ɲ��O���=t����"/���_�zj
>   x�Jӛ���ɗ�����Y���^R継K��ƣ������4{���k������?����/����ڧ��C����������#���^g}���-����|���o>���q܏st�����r��oN�K����g�3Z{{���ey��
>   ���l�-9�y/a���g��ƿo�a*����e�J��ӝO��K��{�;�Oā�=q�O<���C8*
>   �����;���W'�&V2�)���V��t���-�����ͲA�a��ƽ�O�Q�h���x?��Nv�������cru�I�Ȑ�L��ά�|1}Z-�yY�O���CN�^�>4ܭ��m������9m�hO�-L����[�1ת��f&�
>   ��k���{���V���{�� �}������gPL}��ɟ�~�ɵ8g�~JJo/��{@�(zr�v
>   k���~��-X���Z�����^���1iy���`�`����� ��z=�?u�0��x��r��z��B��
>   ��Vp�oX���}V�DW�$)���Y�r]��.�1�8}��4�u}1J_���%������!"�����E�8���r�;����Y�Kܣu��7�>^z��SJ�FE���k��O~9,��t����x2"�C�cD����n����'_�ݿ������:��E��G8Y��������������{o
>   x�h�1��O�8&o�n�����F�����5����z��8������/�삦*=�AN�V���zR'W��.�2}�ח�4�{��%�R�����G��{���+�nz�>���ʖ]��N����:�D0+�u�E��M��G
>   �?@�S�-7[O(czpQ�;��b�n�h�˘>|�1iP����s��aQYE��}������{;l~�E���}�z$/t�i7��a`�
>   �3�|~�1���)�F�ӧ����4�U�yd��},�m�d
>   ~����6�y��X,��p�Z٧�-���x�$#?�~r E6��;\��0�/\��ԹE{�����mb�
>   =�o^Q�cŀ�pI���ŀ(9S���R@~������E�}x0ޅ�Y3��u=e*�{;;�G�޿��d��ŗo����ۤ�)HxZ�)��Y��ӗ�ϟ?Oi|�j�~;��y5,�bl�g���ރ��E���Hf<�+{Xf}q��Á"�=8-�}g��3F���Om�|>(��������<��<@�Y�a�A�����ϟ풫�Q�Y�9@�fs��O����
>   R�r����O�9�_.��$|��)ˀO��^�IUV�<}B�}*o�n���{�'ߤ?Y�U]dw)�OK�(/ti�}*��$�/�n��Fj9���qE0������Uᒏ�!܎�
>   ;����8��*ri����O�N�M��P�?��t���q��P�Ǘ�)Cq|��q|�ܿ�~g���ޞ���{ߔ�s"��ؽG�3�=$��^<}����v�z�����s�";x0&���d���wk;�Vc�����l��uլ2�P[oӦ(\����k]�k��M���S��p+�����y&�0������1v��9�����(T���?�t�!&}#o?t��`����(k�x��|5��d6�=�6��&�z���u
>   �8I�1����,͐��&�~��Cg�����c�7KK�?}�퇷�f�!޾���o�v4����c�55����k5�8�b�W_�$_vY�e��?��Ғ�z:��,��iGMJ����&��U5#ӿ�f����y~~^��g�`�%)���#+�������m�}�����}89�E�$�P�*3(��p�aTf|�{s�n�|�+3�t/*3�s�u�o
>   .gr�'8$�gLo��8������i���iq�B�o�������81{;_���uu��{�0�s��'v�l|�V��k��'���f��ʗt�N�a�}F�FZ��I�#g|����1��e�{c
>   ��U��݇�����-T�����}@��e[˥C���_nXe�����^������.e�����59;N�??��i�E6��Y�$���������UƟn?=��}?��;߀��u������N���9�}o��{�Y��e����x�n�����r���}J�F�J��ה0����?�&��|�S���7�Ow:w��'��wz�V6N�:c�g�dv��ຯ>�$}3)ʢ)�T��B؋��?����e;"Q�_�Y`7���2���YN��9n���;+�Xٸ��ㅋ��0Y��7���Χ���.���޿w/�r��r]�Ӈ�G~���?6F����}D��ۻ��pǥ�=���ۯ�}h�-p7}R����½�+\/-��ӝ�V���O�8We�篑S�������?���Y��7~�p�����^�������O�����.2�>�?�}�{o���}����k��B�mŀd?.����P���[�F�����R�����>�rX
>   �ww>�J��{�:)
>   �`�@'g�;N��ݎo���b����������~iy�Uv���=�i�����X�D��X�@�f�]�~�Y�)yo-��|����3��,���22��6X���!��7Fan)�£�O��#�oq��;�<�O���N��!���{����w\��E��R�P������pbD9�ҟXX���=$4Ĕ��Ý�����=�7V�1�`P1�����t�,��,��5Q;=.x�r$F�w�z��x�I]��!��1Q�2���}��&?��=�!{�z_��5��є{���։��(}C��������ø�|z���
>   ���7�#���
>   ��*D$Ƒ��L��N>�y����D�>�*�~�W�߆�6�§{{���}Z�}��i�Y��poZ&���������<�����a/������ِ�ا���>���$}���o����ѿc��s&Y>��Է�Y�ļ�ΖY�w&ZZI�D'�>��{b��xgu^�_CH��}��{��!�C^߸m��b�'{�K���}��
>   i!堳����{{��1�;q�VK���%H�(�������{��Q)9�o'�y��r��x�JɃ�!)��>����|y�l���&)��4x��ɾ)�w�ɓW���&/�PyQ����&'����7-�,}����z���H���(��>~���P�//>ݽ�<��
>   ��x�{�Y�`Ώę{�� ����k
>   )��x�S�Kf�<����7�Ã^���+�ѓ�=Z���)Z�����������$|J���������Mk0���y�J�����4�my��j$��z�����yQf3b�9+�U^�4��n���{}�����IV�F�u6IOE�m�Z�^dw��b��O��g���R�o���i^������澨ќXQ�������{C�-����{K�����I#��y���w�9j��~�A��#���5���wGK�&���-|�C�Q6��T�țx���΍kF����V�>�n�U����
>   �s����H�2����
>   �aǯ7�����������s9����%�[Zh��يO���u��\ʗ��<]�����}?�I.҃.��8��R���.�8������N���)�
>   �~���?�݇�(�SxB�̇1�����9�\��M���A�o����c�ן�~^Qf����b�9��e�K���iU�*���6��4�ܭoZ�������/aV���ލ��Ɗ��������'4�M'��ý/�O����>t���c��fŁ�Ğ���pr|v�׈��]�g�ao|���^4YEk�;7��}������Y�&���L�V`=fד��9Wu�n�eUr
>   ���ꃝ�����f����3�.����{�7�n�S��w/�|y�����+�����;��QX���S-����V��G�ʶ�_?8pl�)�{J��{lK���I�m܂m������C9�SZX�l{������0מ.&u��'�mw�԰ϋ@&<���"����~7��"_.�h]7m��SR�&����JŉH���a����!��@���
>   �}_[�z���}V���x��{_Yx�����V�;;{��B��,�
>   �.X$vׅ�w��د���>)���Q�|^�M<�鮋�wIO߿�j�?��쁽%�_��IQϢi�'�&ʚ�x6��7�������0���oɗN1�>|�bHJb޿?s_"
>   ��:xHَx�����^�2&-n~��Nǩ�kbH��vc>���
>   ��������O�9u�G��}^�WV}0~�郃ݨAVa�fV=x�-yQ2t@Sn��r3����{����C����>_���
>   ��bIy������QȯN޼L�d�U����K_��*/���c?O�]Z&K��޶�zA�d��R-�p6����qq��2���D~O�>�=��}S9;��$���'H�������},�mtǱ��SZ��J��o�$r�)���Ç�;��X���n��u�EV���F�Ƞ�z����!E���;���P
>   �#jD��2�k�7�h}�����՞ x��9V�a�d�h��xI�\gݼ�7�~*a�-$`��$78�L
>   �����='�Һ1\�"��#�>�y��C_^���O?5D��C�*(��s)�P�#a��#�bm
>   y���s�s���������?=}��[�7��8?�2�p��>��F�S�Ͽ�`��Y��3���-�R������{
>   =,�@\:Y�G�B����8������O��e~N9�����'�eh��y��y�皩G��E�q0�������qc���?;!���}���އD������
>   �r�3{��X����'_n?�V\Z<<�tJGZ8�q�<��q��V11e$����~���O=a!�Aݭ
>   �����f'���BV��yNؽO����{��<�
>   r�x��l2�$LNZ�z��,}�.�V��3�q�2'^i$����=Y���W��:�7��AD�Ɀ?����拾i�P��"r�*�}��������<���;7�������;����3h�!ٿ��~GF��ƩzH�.)�C�%��o�T���^��䂼���wH���O�GsE��߻Y.x�"���w����jc3�������h'�t�E��zYL�n�ֲ��/>�k�\s�׷���o;�'�m�i�������;�%�������������p�����-�G3B=>�O�b��9}��~��*M�t�����������K=�'^�������Kb�^�s����dT����׿W��m���b��9Ky����'#_�l�S�߳���X>�[���E"����6`���Ϛ�����"���\܃��>rq������tSr
>   S)����΀�t�`�V�����ٻב�{��T�˲k������.����T�ěW������{H����{��!l��H��u�P�����Ӟ��}C��ݩ�;�Zg`gP�'9nu��;W����
>   7 '�������!6�4;��G���
>   �>@��������D�"e�����#���[���{q�y@�n����E�#":�ƴ��΁�R�+.-}8i9��ɓ�IQ/��<[؅�~cF����Ev��ڈ�}�+���Ow>���C�'O(?�2"�*��(Jy�P���m���."f��3�{;Y��)���@����
>   WYd��`J��y!�eT��@�����n��6�;~��҈co���c/R
>   �K)\��w|YT�&��)1��YUu��x�ìtLy�ǒ���h���O����<��ha!?�xa��K�y/U�&����I#������k�2���{7���}s�Sh�L�c��_�����_>��/�Y����0_�
>   ��.I��!_��4�������+_"����_�̗Fc~_���ȗ����ݧ��0�%�>�~���ě+�~�c����Blzo�x�v���y�0�d�*�΃O�#��$eh�rSd0�&(���;c�x����
>   އ������<���7�{�����n��]���ٹ'����O���E��������YZ�>�?������'�M���H�f=0s��(�����x�V��p�6�O������z�f��晿wN���N��A2v'~o�>�Ӿ���f�����gsķ���`��n0�{;{�Y���ó�`�,�����ͤ��x�t���O����\�����݇�g�CݻA5��g��~��s��YB�`�#s^�zs������Ov��#6����1��)��ɿ�]F��O~7�=4���f�{vy�^T=�����Й����/NهM��M��0����c���¬O�=7�{�aR~�����;�y�c8��v�(,�4M�G~4K���݇7̒��Izr�I�w�$ݣЉ'~4K������{�B��{kY�wo�4<|��o��}J��������\����������
>   ?2�1����tw���޿�����?�}�l������q/�ާ݅��oN�9:��� ���]
>   �0�;-��o|�SK���}��}�Ʀ���S��SS�9���oh�)�y��\��̳�d~/�����E��k�3�7E7ݼƃ[��N$����ރ������<����>�$Id���g��`�����L�����
>   ����
>   �(�,�;�|Ӷ~��P�?|��d�?���6��}�VmVO1��ˬi�^�.L�FY���}�p��V�y��.i1�g����Ã_���/z

Comment: If my answer worked for you please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the Content-Encoding headers are `Content-Encoding: gzip` which arent readable. The following code should work for you!

```
// jSON URL which should be requested
$json_url = 'http://can.vicosh.ro:8000/VirtualRadar/AircraftList.json';

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip'
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$result = curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string
echo $result;
```